# C# : How to cast an object to ItemSource data type?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, wpf-controls

I am trying to develop a custom User control. In my User Control I use two controls a List Box and a Text Box. Text Box is use for filtering items in List Box.  To doing this I am facing a problem in my filter method. In my filter method I need to cast object to ItemSource type. But I don`t understand how can I cast it. Here is my Code which I try:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSourrce", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(SSSearchListBox), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as SSSearchListBox;
        if (control != null)
            control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue);

    }

    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        // Remove handler for oldValue.CollectionChanged 
        var oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (null != oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
        }
        // Add handler for newValue.CollectionChanged (if possible) 
        var newValueINotifyCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (null != newValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
        }
    }

    void newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do your stuff here. 

    } 

    public IEnumerable ItemSourrce
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)this.GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }
public void TextFiltering(ICollectionView filteredview, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit textBox)
    {
        string filterText = "";
        filteredview.Filter = delegate(object obj)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
            {
                return true;
            }
            string str = obj as string; // Problem is here.
                                        // I need to cast obj to my ItemSourrce Data Type.
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()))
            {
                return true;
            }

            int index = str.IndexOf(filterText, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            return index > -1;
        };
        textBox.EditValueChanging += delegate
        {
            filterText = textBox.Text;
            filteredview.Refresh();
        };
    }

    private void textEdit1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemSourrce);
        TextFiltering(view, textEdit1);
    }
```

calling this Use Control :

```
   List<testClass> myList = new List<testClass>();
    public void testMethod()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(new testClass { testData=i.ToString()});
        } 
        myTestControl.ItemSourrce = myList;
    }

    public class testClass
    {
      public string testData { get; set; }
    }
```

thank`s

Answer (score 0):

well everything what you want to assing to ItemSource (or ItemsSource for naming consistence) has to implement the IEnumerable interface. Thist means basicaly erverything you can iterate through a foreach (to put it simply). So every List, array, collections, Dictionaries and so on.

Normaly you can't iterate throu a normal out of the box string!

So if your Object is realy a String (check it with a breakpoint on debugging) you have to split it somehow.

ps: by the way this code

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()))
{
   return true;
}
```

never (except some rare unmeaningfull example where you explicitly return an empty string for ToStirng()) returns true because obj.ToString() is never null or Empty. In the standard implementation of the type Object (which every .net Type is based on) it returns the Namespace and the name of the type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your objects are of type `testClass` and not of `string`.

So you code should be where you try to do the casting.

```
string str = string.Empty;

testClass myObject = obj as testClass;

if (myObject == null)
    return true;
else
    str = myObject.testData;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    return true;

return str.IndexOf(filterText, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
```

Comment: Yes i agree with you.
 But if i put   myTestControl1.ItemSourrce = myList1;
And myTestControl2.ItemSourrce = myList2;
Then what will be happen? I want to use my control like as a list Box.

Comment: @Hasan009 As long as both ItemsSource are of type testClass it will work correctly. Because you assign the filter to a specific view everytime. It is not the same filter for all your views.

Comment: Actually i want to get the type of my ItemSourrce. In this case data type is testClass.I want to use my control in several project`s so there data source will be change.